# Referring to a method of a class and behaviour of `this`

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I create a class, then I can use `this` within methods to set and retrive properties. However, `this` becomes undefined if I use a variable to refer to a method, as with variable `b` below:

```js
class MyClass {
    methodA() {
        return this;
    }
}

var a = new MyClass();
var b = a.methodA;

console.log(a.methodA());
console.log(b());
```

Output:

```
MyClass {}
undefined
```

Why don't the log statements produce the same output?

Comment: var b = () => a.methodA();

Comment: assigning method in this case without binding context would automatically set context (`this`) to global, which lead to your unexpected output. Changing to `var b = a.methodA.bind(a)`  would help you

Comment: I think this question not dublicate

Comment: When you call var b = a.methodA; b will be underline it only return when you call a.methodA()
```
class MyClass {
    methodA() {
        return this;
    }
}

var a = new MyClass();
var b = a.methodA();

console.log(a.methodA());
console.log(b());

```
Output:
```
MyClass {}
MyClass {}
```